# How to optimize architecture in a database

Tags: mysql, database, storage

I'm a beginner and I want to know what is the best way for the architecture of a bdd, I give you an example:

I have a user table:

```
  CREATE TABLE `users` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `pseudo` varchar(50) NOT NULL)
```

In my process I have some survey who have a state `waiting,work,ended` and I need to store the ID of the survey too.

**So the first possibility** is to create a table survey who have this value :

```
CREATE TABLE `user_survey` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `userId` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `state` smallint(3) NOT NULL)
```

But in my backend I need to question 2 time if I want take the user, and search for his surveys.

**The second possibility** is to add a row in `user` table called `survey` and store the data like this : `surveyId,stateSurvey;surveyId,stateSurvey` etc. And iterate this data in my backend to search all survey I need.

What is the best practice/way to get this kind of data. And there is other way more "simple"?

Comment: The most common is approach two because it reduces typing errors (plain wrong typing errors and or case sensitive) and diskspace vs approach one.. And use a JOIN with user table when searching on a survey state or name.

Comment: @RaymondNijland thank to your reply, so I will make like the second approach !

Comment: "I think Raymond has been smoking something" No @Strawberry but iam pretty tired for some hours now

Comment: "reduces typing errors" more possibilities of errors in the second possibilities no ?

Comment: ""reduces typing errors" more possibilities of error in the second possibilities no ?" i mean with data integrity the normalized method is less error prone  @El-Burritos

Comment: @RaymondNijland Ok thanks !

Comment: You might like to read [my answer to Is storing a delimited list in a database column really that bad?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653462/is-storing-a-delimited-list-in-a-database-column-really-that-bad/3653574#3653574)